# MySql output into csv does not work ERROR 1045 (28000)

Tags: mysql, bash, export-to-csv

I am trying to write a bash script running on a server.
The result should be a .csv with my select query.

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u u65654db3 --password="dk3T" -h localhost <<EOF
Use u65654db3
Select * from data
into outfile '/data/web/e54/html/output.txt'
EOF
```

So this above script is working, it outputs my query to output.txt but when I change it to:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u u65654db3 --password="dk3T" -h localhost <<EOF
Use u65654db3
Select * from data
into outfile '/data/web/e54/html/test.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
EOF
```

I get this error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000) at line 2: Access denied for user 'u65654db3'@'%' (using password: YES)

I also checked the Grants:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for u65654db3@%                                   |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'u65654db3'@'%'                    |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'u65654db3'.* TO 'u65654db3'@'%' |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Are you sure that this problem is reproducible?  Try removing the `LINES TERMINATED BY` clause, as `\n` is the default already.

Comment: is 'u65654db3'@'%' the only user of that name?

Comment: You may try to move database name from stdin to param or to terminate commands in your stdin (semicolon). For me it looks like the issue somehow related to the field termination semicolon and missing semicolon between USE and SELECT commands.